# AngularJs bootstrap and charts

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, charts

I am working on a project that involves building a line chart. I am getting the data from a mysql DB. I want to know how its possible to use AngularJs and some bootstrap templates to accomplish this. I would very much appreciate it if there is a step by step way of explaining.

thank you in advance

Comment: you can try http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ for responsive(bootstrap) charts with angular

Answer (score 0):

Try using AngularJS service to read the data from your Back end server via HTTP REST API or url that returns json.

Then use nvd3-angular-directive library to show the chart e.g https://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html

Comment: thanks for the help. I ma working with the library and i can't see to figure out some of the directives. like,  xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormat()". I don't know how to override this (if its possible). my data is a CPU usage data. so time Vs cpu percent. would you happen to have any idea on how i can accomplish this ?

Comment: xAxisTickFormat() is just a function name, you need to define xAxisTickFormat() inside the controller that is binded to the html template where you see detailed example: https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/blob/master/examples/lineChart.html   for more examples check: https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/tree/master/examples